# Does Source Safe 2005 allow you to change formatting on checkin?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, code-formatting

Different developers use different fonts in Visual Studio. However, this is becoming a problem when people check in code because Source Safe apparently retains the formatting information. Is there a hook that source safe provides to update formatting on the code before it checks in to ensure that the checked in code is using the standard font? Why does Source Safe even worry about font face to begin with?

Thanks,
Ashish

UPDATE: I misunderstood the email that prompted this question. My bad!

Comment: Different fonts?  Or do you mean tabs vs. spaces?  Or is this for non-code files?  What sort of projects/code is this?

Comment: @cfeduke - Its for a VB.NET project that has .vb and .sql files but I was recently informed that i misunderstood the email that prompted this question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The font used in Visual Studio is a user setting, stored in a *.vssettings file: you should not check these in unless you want to share them across your team.

If you want to share *some* settings, but not the font, remove that from the team settings file you're using (specified at Options -> Environment -> Import and Export Settings).